# Is Android Device Policy Management possible with system apps only

Tags: android

I have written an app that enforces device policy management to enforce PIN and screen lock (similar to http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/device-management-policy.html) and intend to ultimately have it on Google PlayStore. 
Does my app need to be signed with system certificate in order for it be able to enforce these device management policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, your app will have certain rights and **will not require any system certificate**, it will **just require approval from the user** to allow your app to act as an administrator.

Kindly download the sample app from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/device-management-policy.html).
As shown in below image it will ask permission from user and that's it.

[image]

```
Will google allow to upload such app on Play-store ?
```

Yes definitely, It will allow for sure. Google have disclosed this API for such kind of apps. In playstore, there are many apps which are acting as administrator with this API. i.e. [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock), [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost)

Comment: But http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#how says that "A system administrator writes a device admin application that enforces remote/local device security policies."

Comment: @learner_21: your app will be one of the administrators once user approves the request. just download and run the demo app, approve the request and you will see the name of the app inside `Settings>Security>Device administrators`

Comment: @ Mehul Thanks for your help on this. I have already implemented this in my app and yes I am able to see it Settings>Security>Device administrators. I am only worried whether Google will allow me to have this app on PlayStore since it enforces device admin policies. I havn't come across a PlayStore downloaded app which enforces these kind of policies.

Comment: @learner_21: Yes definitely, It will allow for sure. they have disclosed this API for such kind of apps. In playstore, there are many apps which are acting as administrator with this API. i.e. [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock), [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost)